Praying but need seated support for specific parts
Al Salamu Alaykum,
So in my case I have an ingrown toenail and I can do all parts of prayer except that when I go down for sujood and get up from sujoof back to standing I have to alter the way I get up to avoid aching the toe and this is a bit uncomfortable. And in addition when sitting in between the two prostrations I experience pain on the toe.
However for the actual sujood itself I can do it normally.
Im not sure if i should pray standing and then use a chair to sit on when it’s time to go down to sujood until we get up from sujood to the other rakah, or should I pray standing and then only use a chair for the sitting between the two prostrations, therefore meaning that I would get dow to sujood and do sujood and get up from sujood back to standing as I normally would.

You must do what you are able to do. If the pain is bearable then endure it. If it is not bearable then do the minimum possible to be able to pray. Maybe you can lean on a support or adjust your sitting position.
